# android permissions to list assets subdirectory files

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I would like to list files contained into assets subdirectory called "subDir" and am using following code. However, if I set dirFrom = "" (empty), lists all folders in assets properly. However, for dirFrom = "/subDir/", doesn't work. I already tried "subDir/" and same result. Is necessary to declare permissions in manifest? Thank you.

```
private void copyFiles(String dirFrom, String dirTo) throws IOException {

    AssetManager am = getAssets();

    String fileList[] = am.list(dirFrom);

        if (fileList != null)
        {   
            for ( int i = 0;i<fileList.length;i++)
            {   
                Log.d("",fileList[i]); 
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Paths should have no `/` in the end. Have you tried just `subdir`?

Comment: sure, syntax error! Thanks! I could not validate a comment, please post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AssetManager.list(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list%28java.lang.String%29) takes a "relative path within the assets".

Android / Java usually expects paths to have no `'/'` in the end.

Also "relative" means that there should be no `'/'` at the start - it could otherwise be a path in the root of your filesystem.

Using just `"subDir"` or `"subDir/subsubDir"` will work.

Answer (score 0):

zapl´s answer is true, but additional info: If You want to copy the files, for example to sd card, You have to declare Your InputStream with a slash:

```
    InputStream in = assetManager.open("subDir/"+filename);
```

This was something I have stumbled by copy files from a subfolder. My originally plan was to copy files directly from asset folder, this worked but gave me some IOExceptions. There were some directories "webkit","sound","images" and another one I can´t remember, inside the asset folder...but I have not seen them. This must be something Android internal that I don´t understand. But to get rid of this, I placed my files inside a subfolder. I know it is an old thread, but I put this information to this thread only to help others with similar problems.